# Spark write stream to IBM Cloud object storage failing with "Access KEY is empty. Please provide valid access key"

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, ibm-cloud-storage, stocator

I am currently using Apache Spark 2.3.2 and creating a pipeline to read stream csv files from a file system and then write stream it to IBM Cloud object storage.

I am using [Stocator](https://github.com/CODAIT/stocator) connector for this. The regular read and writes to IBM COS is working fine with the below configuration. But , the read and write stream operations are throwing error as:

> com.ibm.stocator.fs.common.exception.ConfigurationParseException: Configuration parse exception: Access KEY is empty. Please provide valid access key

**The stocator config** :

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.cos.impl","com.ibm.stocator.fs.ObjectStoreFileSystem")    
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.stocator.scheme.list","cos")    
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.stocator.cos.impl","com.ibm.stocator.fs.cos.COSAPIClient")    
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.stocator.cos.scheme", "cos")    
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.cos.Cloud Object Storage-POCDL.endpoint", "{url}")    
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.cos.Cloud Object Storage-POCDL.access.key", "{access_key}")    
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.cos.Cloud Object Storage-POCDL.secret.key", {secret_key})
```

**readstream** :

```
val csvDF = sqlContext
.readStream
.option("sep", ",")
.schema(fschema)
.csv({path})
```

**writestream**:

```
val query = csvDF
.writeStream
.outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
.format("parquet")
.option("checkpointLocation", "cos://stream-csv.Cloud Object Storage-POCDL/")
.option("path", "cos://stream-csv.Cloud Object Storage-POCDL/")
.start()
```

**Error Logs :**

`"2018-12-17 16:51:14 WARN  FileStreamSinkLog:66 - Could not use FileContext API for managing metadata log files at path cos://stream-csv.Cloud Object Storage-POCDL/_spark_metadata. Using FileSystem API instead for managing log files. The log may be inconsistent under failures.
2018-12-17 16:51:14 INFO  ObjectStoreVisitor:110 - Stocator registered as cos for cos://stream-csv.Cloud Object Storage-POCDL/_spark_metadata
2018-12-17 16:51:14 INFO  COSAPIClient:251 - Init :  cos://stream-csv.Cloud Object Storage-POCDL/_spark_metadata
Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.stocator.fs.common.exception.ConfigurationParseException: Configuration parse exception: Access KEY is empty. Please provide valid access key"`

Is there any way to resolve this error or another alternative to arrive to a solution?

**Updated with more logs**:

```
scala>  val csvDF = spark.readStream.option("sep", ",").schema(fschema).csv("C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\stream")
csvDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [EMP_NO: string, EMP_SALARY: string ... 2 more fields]

scala>  val query = csvDF.writeStream.outputMode(OutputMode.Append()).format("csv").option("checkpointLocation", "cos://stream-csv.Cloud Object Storage-POCDL/").option("path", "cos://stream-csv.Cloud Object Storage-POCDL/").start()
18/12/18 10:47:40 WARN FileStreamSinkLog: Could not use FileContext API for managing metadata log files at path cos://stream-csv.Cloud%20Object%20Storage-POCDL/_spark_metadata. Using FileSystem API instead for managing log files. The log may be inconsistent under failures.
18/12/18 10:47:40 DEBUG ObjectStoreVisitor: Stocator schema space : cos, provided cos. Implementation com.ibm.stocator.fs.cos.COSAPIClient
18/12/18 10:47:40 INFO ObjectStoreVisitor: Stocator registered as cos for cos://stream-csv.Cloud%2520Object%2520Storage-POCDL/_spark_metadata
18/12/18 10:47:40 DEBUG ObjectStoreVisitor: Load implementation class com.ibm.stocator.fs.cos.COSAPIClient
18/12/18 10:47:40 DEBUG ObjectStoreVisitor: Load direct init for COSAPIClient. Overwrite com.ibm.stocator.fs.cos.COSAPIClient
18/12/18 10:47:40 INFO COSAPIClient: Init :  cos://stream-csv.Cloud%2520Object%2520Storage-POCDL/_spark_metadata
18/12/18 10:47:40 DEBUG ConfigurationHandler: COS driver: initialize start for cos://stream-csv.Cloud%2520Object%2520Storage-POCDL/_spark_metadata
18/12/18 10:47:40 DEBUG ConfigurationHandler: extracted host name from cos://stream-csv.Cloud%2520Object%2520Storage-POCDL/_spark_metadata is stream-csv.Cloud%20Object%20Storage-POCDL
18/12/18 10:47:40 DEBUG ConfigurationHandler: Initiaize for bucket: stream-csv, service: Cloud%20Object%20Storage-POCDL
18/12/18 10:47:40 DEBUG ConfigurationHandler: Filesystem cos://stream-csv.Cloud%2520Object%2520Storage-POCDL/_spark_metadata, using conf keys for fs.cos.Cloud%20Object%20Storage-POCDL. Alternative list [fs.s3a.Cloud%20Object%20Storage-POCDL, fs.s3d.Cloud%20Object%20Storage-POCDL]
18/12/18 10:47:40 DEBUG ConfigurationHandler: Initialize completed successfully for bucket stream-csv service Cloud%20Object%20Storage-POCDL
18/12/18 10:47:40 DEBUG MemoryCache: Guava initiated with size 2000 expiration 30 seconds
18/12/18 10:47:40 ERROR ObjectStoreVisitor: Configuration parse exception: Access KEY is empty. Please provide valid access key
com.ibm.stocator.fs.common.exception.ConfigurationParseException: Configuration parse exception: Access KEY is empty. Please provide valid access key
at com.ibm.stocator.fs.cos.COSAPIClient.initiate(COSAPIClient.java:276)
at com.ibm.stocator.fs.ObjectStoreVisitor.getStoreClient(ObjectStoreVisitor.java:130)
at com.ibm.stocator.fs.ObjectStoreFileSystem.initialize(ObjectStoreFileSystem.java:105)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2669)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog$FileSystemManager.<init>(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:409)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog.createFileManager(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:292)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog.<init>(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog.<init>(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSinkLog.<init>(FileStreamSinkLog.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink.<init>(FileStreamSink.scala:98)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createSink(DataSource.scala:317)
at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:293)
... 49 elided
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tested streaming and seems working for me, I tested a bit similar code

```
val userSchema = spark.read.parquet("/mydata/test.parquet").schema
val streamDf = spark.readStream.schema(userSchema).parquet("/mydata/")
    streamDf.writeStream.format("parquet").option("checkpointLocation",
    "cos://bucket.my_service/").option("path","cos://bucket.my_service").start()
```

What Stocator version you are using? You can see this from the log, USER AGENT header

Comment: I am using the Stocator version v1.0.28. I have also updated the post with more logs if it helps.

Comment: The log contains service_name as 'Cloud%2520Object%2520Storage-POCDL'
While your configuration has "fs.cos.service_name.access.key".

<service_name> from the configuration should be identical to the <service_name> you use in URL.

for example you need to have fs.cos.Cloud%2520Object%2520Storage-POCDL.access.key", but i am not sure if "service_name" allows special chars

Comment: I have updated the configuration now. Earlier, I had just mentioned the template. So I mentioned "service name"
Also, as i said in my post, the read stream works absolutely fine, which means the special characters should not be an issue. the issue is only with write stream.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the issue and proposed solution is [here](http://github.com/CODAIT/stocator/issues/205).